# Colon is Missing In My Website Url in Wordpress

Tags: php, shortcode, urls

```
add_action( 'init', function() {

    add_shortcode( 'site_url', function( $atts = null, $content = null ) {
        return site_url();
    });

});
```

I'm Using The Short Code **[`site_url`]** and My Short Code Function Returned `https//shad-pro.com/contact-us`

How Do I get The Proper `Url` With Colon **`:`**

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3xwL.png)

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your wp_options table under the column "site_url". The Colon can be missing in database table.

Comment: Sorry For The Late Reply But Yes I Checked In My DB The url is Proper With Colon..